# Hypercube inscribed with a hypersphere

Tags: geometry, multivariable-calculus

Consider a n-dimensional hypercube of side length 2, and a maximally inscribed n-dimensional hypersphere of radius 1 centered around origin. What is the total volume of all smaller hypercubes on corners , where one corner (a) of those small hypercubes is the corner of the larger hypercube, and the other touches the closest point from the corner (a) to the inscribed sphere.

An example would be n=2, it is simply a square with an inscribed sphere.  The diagonal of the small cubes is $\sqrt{2}-1$. The volume of one small cube is $(\sqrt{2}-1)^2/2$.

when n=3 there should be 8 such small cubes.

I am particularly interested when n=4, where they are 16 such small cubes.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Your solution for $n=2$ can be extended for any $n$: compute the diagonal of the hypercubes, and find out how to compute the volume of a hypercube given the length of the diagonal